# "Hardware Drivers" item missing from menu

Tags: 10.10, drivers, nvidia

I just installed the newest version of Ubuntu (10.10) and I am trying to get the appropriate drivers installed for the nvidia ion.

However there is no system > administration > hardware drivers option in the toolbar. Does this not exist in this version of ubuntu?

Do you know of any good links to installing the right drivers for the nvidia ion on ubuntu?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 11):

The tool is now called "Additional Drivers".

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Just press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and type `jockey-gtk`. You will always open the Hardware Drivers no matter what the name in the menu is.

In 12.10 this has been merged into **System Settings**. You can now click on the Cog icon (Top right corner) and select System Settings. In the system section click on **Software Sources**. The last tab will be **Additional Hardware** and it will have a very easy way of managing the drivers versions and different drivers for each hardware device.

As mentioned by Søren Løvborg, you can go directly to this by typing **software sources** in the dash search.

Comment: This has been merged into `software-properties-gtk` in Ubuntu 12.10 (quantal).

Answer (score 2):

The name was change to **Additional Drivers** as one of the **One Hundred Paper Cuts**. See here : [Change the name of "Hardware drivers"](https://bugs.launchpad.net/hundredpapercuts/+bug/409338)

The principal reason for the change was that the name **Hardware Drivers** was confusing as the tool only manage non-free drivers and not all the drivers.