# Hardware Divers option is not there

Tags: 10.10, drivers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“Hardware Drivers” item missing from menu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16508/hardware-drivers-item-missing-from-menu)

I just installed the newest version of Ubuntu (10.10) and I am trying to get the appropriate drivers installed for the nvidia ion.

However there is no system > administration > hardware drivers option in the toolbar. Does this not exist in this version of ubuntu?

Do you know of any good links to installing the right drivers for the nvidia ion on ubuntu?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: System->Administration->Additional Drivers ??

Answer (score 1):

The name was change to **Additional Drivers** as one of the **One Hundred Paper Cuts**. See here : [Change the name of "Hardware drivers"](https://bugs.launchpad.net/hundredpapercuts/+bug/409338)

The principal reason for the change was that the name **Hardware Drivers** was confusing as the tool only manage non-free drivers and not all the drivers.